# Displaying data in html file from json using Angular2

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to pass data from a json feed to the html file, the below is not working.

**app.component.html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let unit of units">
  <li>
    {{unit.details.count}} // getting data OK result -> 5642
  </li>
  <li>
    {{unit.cars.vehicle_id}} // not getting data
  </li>
</ul>
```

**units_feed.json**

```
[{"details":{"count":"5642"},"cars":[{"vehicle_id":"2056437754"},{"vehicle_id":"2056437753"},{"vehicle_id":"2056356347"},{"vehicle_id":"2056437752"},{"vehicle_id":"2056395634"}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant access it as `unit.cars` is an array of object. If You wanted to access one of those objects i.e. ones with the `vehicle_id` you could use `{{unit.cars[0].vehicle_id}}`. Notice the `[0]` that telling it to access the first item in the array and the you can view its property `vehicle_id`.

Would guess you would have to do something like this

```
<ul *ngFor="let unit of units">
  <li>
    {{unit.details.count}} 
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let car of unit.cars">{{car.vehicle_id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, well explained.